# VSCode: disable Java linting

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode with Java Extension Pack installed.

I want to temporarily disable linting/error highlighting in a single Java file. In user settings I only see linting-related settings for all the other languages (HTML, CSS, PHP, Ruby, Python) *except* Java.

A workaround would be to disable Java Extension Pack completely and restart VSCode but I would like to find a more elegant solution if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your question was not clear so I will write about two possible issues you might be experiencing.

1:

You have Java Extension Pack installed and want to disable it's linting.
Go to the extension page, find your extension and click disable / remove extension. If you've disabled the extension you can restart it at anytime.

2:

You have Java Extension Pack installed that has Java linting in it but you can not see it, instead it is marking your Java files as other languages. You are now seeing linting but not for your Java language extension.
If this is the case should see the name of the linted language in the bottom blue bar, on the right. click it and change it to Java. You should be good to go.

Comment: Updated my question. I want to disable Java linting, yes. I know that I can disable the extension pack completely but would prefer a more elegant solution if possible.

Comment: You can go to settings and search for "lint", you should be able to disable it from there, specific for a language you choose

Comment: As already mentioned in my question, I did that but there seem to be `lint` settings for all the other languages (HTML, CSS, PHP, Ruby, Python) *except* Java.

Comment: This problem was so annoying, I disabled the Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat Extension, this was the part of Extension Pack for Java. If incase any one is still looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

searching this you can disable it: @ext:redhat.java hint